# How can i change the name of the input in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i want change the name of the input to make it `name=data[Contact][firstname]` because I want to display the data when i click edit() i guess that is the reason why it is not displaying. `echo $this->Form->input('First Name:', array('class'=>'form-control'));` the name of the input is same n the first param. please help

Comment: Maybe you want to change the label of the input?

Comment: how to add value attribute in a form using cakephp sir? because i have a data i want to put in the input value for edit purpose.

Comment: You should read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts). Data is passed to the form so inputs should be populated in the edit form.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do as it is not clear? What is your current code and why exactly do you want to change the `name` attribute?

Comment: I set the data i send to edit method in the controller to make it display as a default value for edit purpose sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>'First Name'));
```

Comment: sir i followed this. But still I can't display the data i set in the controller to display as the default value of inputs when edit button is click.

Comment: i set a value property to the data from the data 
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'form-control', 
 'label'=>'First Name:', 'default'=>$contact['Contact']['firstname'])); to make it as a default value. And now i am able to edit the current data. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is the name of the input field (name="firstname"). It is not the label (First name: ). so your code should be,

```
$this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

To get this structure [Contact][firstname], your form name should be 'contact'.

```
$this->Form->create('Contact',array('class'=>'form'));
    $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

Comment: sir i followed this. But still I can't display the data i set in the controller to display as the default value of inputs when edit button is click.

Comment: i set a value property to the data from the data 
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'form-control', 
 'label'=>'First Name:', 'default'=>$contact['Contact']['firstname'])); to make it as a default value. And now i am able to edit the current data. Thank you sir!